# Django migration error: App doesn't provide model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a situation where I have to move a model from app B to app A. For this I created 3 migrations:

1. An auto migration that creates the "destination" model for all the data in the old model
2. A manual migration that deletes the model from app B
3. Another manual migration that creates a ProxyModel where the deleted model was (so other apps can still find the moved model in the place it was)

I renamed the table and faked the creation of the destination model, I also faked the deletion of the moved model (because those were done directly in the DBMS, so I wouldn't lose data) but I'm stuck in the last step because when I try to run the migration that creates the proxy model, the other models that had relations to the moved model complain that app B doesn't provide the (now moved) model:

> ValueError: The field b_app.BModel.afield was declared with a lazy reference to 'b_app.moved_model', but app 'b_app' doesn't provide model 'moved_model'.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide code for your models?